# How to merge rows with nearest values in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
index B
0     1
1     2
2     5
3     6
4     7
5     10
```

And i need to merge rows where the difference is less than or equal 2, select the line with the smaller value and set count merges

The result should be like this :

```
index B count
0     1   2
1     5   3
2     10  1
```

How can this be solved using pandas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very similar [to @AndrejKesely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77251475), just shorter syntax, using [named aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
df.groupby(df["B"].diff().gt(2).cumsum(), 
           as_index=False).agg(B=("B", "first"), 
                               count=("B", "count"))
```

Output:

```
    B  count
0   1      2
1   5      3
2  10      1
```

Comment: Can you use library `numpy` ?

Comment: @XMehdi01 I am sorry, I don't understand the question?   You want to use np.cumsum?

Comment: yes of course it is possible

Answer (score 5):

Use `.groupby()` where you do `.diff()` followed by `.cumsum()`:

```py
out = (
    df.groupby(df["B"].diff().gt(2).cumsum())
    .agg({"B": ("min", "count")})
    .droplevel(0, axis=1)
    .rename(columns={"min": "B"})
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
    B  count
0   1      2
1   5      3
2  10      1
```